# Count matched fields in h2 database

Tags: sql, h2

I would like to count the matched columns of a query with the h2 database.

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ((field1 = ?) + (field2 = ?)) as Matched
FROM mytable
```

But this doe not return any row.

The arithmetic `((field1 = ?) + (field2 = ?))1` may not be good (at least with h2 - because it work with MySQL), any thoughts ?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the `> 1` in your query?

Comment: Try `cast((field1 = ?) as int) + cast((field2 = ?) as int)`

Comment: Thank you, the `cast` was the thing.

Comment: `((field1 = ?) + (field2 = ?))` makes no sense because the result of `field1 = ?` is a `boolean` and the `+` operator is for numbers, not for `boolean` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to MySql, H2 does not automatically coerce a boolean into a number when you apply `+` to it. So convert the booleans explicitly to numbers with `cast`:

```
cast((field1 = ?) as int) + cast((field2 = ?) as int)
```